# Where is the function $f(w)=\int_{\partial D'}\frac{h(z)}{z-w} \, dz$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h(z):D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a complex analytic function defined on a domain $D.$ Suppose that $D'$ is another domain such that $\partial D'$ is a loop in $D.$ Then is the function
$$f(w)=\int_{\partial D'}\frac{h(z)}{z-w} \, dz$$ an analytic function on $D'?$

Note here that we define a *domain* as an open set of $\mathbb{C}$ such that any two points in the domain can be connected by a finite number of straight-line segments.

I believe this fact is true, but I am not entirely sure about how to go about proving such a statement. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: My first thought is Morera's theorem, but maybe there are complications.

Comment: this is true even if $h$ is just continuous, you can differentiate the integral w.r.t. $w$

Comment: Adding to @user8268's comment, you need the Leibniz integral rule, which allows you to swap integrals and derivatives if they're wrt different variables.